# Show advertisement on link click, before redirecting to link href

Tags: javascript, onclick

i want to add on-click function with this a-href tag to display my advertisement link
i tried below codings

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" onlick="javascript:return func();" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

this one with the function

```
func()
{
window.open("xxxxx.html");
return false;
}
```

but it dint work for me so please help me..
i want to display my advertisement when user click the link at the same time it goes to the _permalink in wordpress this is the help i need. is there is any other way kindly help me

Comment: bad heading for question!

Comment: onlick with a "c" -> onclick !

Comment: your code say 'onlick', rather than 'onclick'. Correct that and see if it works

Comment: sorry for the spelling mistake... it still dnt work

Comment: you need to add a meaningful heading!!!

Comment: Check your console and see if func is defined

Comment: it is defined... i want to open two windows at the same time.. one is permalink and otherone is onclick link.. is there any other way

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" onclick="func()" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
  <script>
    function func()
    {
      window.open("xxxxx.html", '_blank');
      return false;
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Explain why you vote down.. otherwise it's useless.. honestly

Comment: i want to open two windows at the same time... it will only opens one window

Comment: i give my google adsense script into xxxxx.html but it dont work for me

Comment: Well, that's another question.. please edit your question or post another one.

Answer (score -1):

rewrite:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" onclick="javascript:return func();" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```